# Sharepoint Workflow doesn't display user profiles EmployeeID

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, user-profile-property

I have sharepoint list and workflow on it, when list item is created workflow must assignee one of the list column 'PerNumber' to user property 'EmployeeID', the problem here is that when list item is created column 'PerNumber' is empty. but in workflow if I change EmployeeID to for example user properties 'Title' or 'Departament' the 'PerNumber' list column shows 'Title' or 'Departament'.  EmployeeID is attribute synchronized from AD

sorry for bad format of question

[image: workflowImage]

Comment: Which version of SharePoint and how are you getting the EmployeeID from the User Profile Data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check the "EmployeeID" in User Profiles in CA, ensure it has values.**

Navigate to User Profile Service Application -> Manage User properties, ensure the property has a mapping to import an AD attribute from the source data connection to this property.

Check the profile of the user, User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Profiles, see if it has value. If not, perform a full sync and see if it is updated.

**Then, Check the "EmployeeID" in the User Information List. Check if it has values.**

1. Navigate to the User Information List via `http://siteurl/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`
2. Settings -> List Settings

   [image]
3. Display the "EmployeeID" and check the value.

If it does not have value in User Information List, run the following timer job to synchronize the User Profile user Data with user Information List

1. User Profile to SharePoint Quick Sync
2. User Profile to SharePoint Full Sync

Information about User Profiles and User Information List:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/User-Information-List-in-8b420e8c